# Cannot create a row of size XXXX which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060 using to_sql/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm taking parquet files and inserting them into a db. Some of these files contain many columns. Most of the files seem to be making it in their respective table, although I see this error every so often:

> Cannot create a row of size XXXX which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060

Since some files are making it into their respective table and some files are not making it into that same table, does that mean that the file that is not making it in just has too much text?

Just trying to make sure I'm understanding this correctly as well as if there is anything I can do to still get that data into my db?

Thanks!

SIDE NOTE: When I get this error, it's telling me that it originates from a line of code that does this:

`[SQL: ALTER TABLE [application] ADD PRIMARY KEY (StagingID);]`

Though, I know I have a `to_sql()` insertion happening before that so I'm assuming that's where the actual error is coming from, but I thought I'd just add this caveat just in case.

Comment: This is a fundamental limitation of SQL Server -- the fixed-size elements of a row cannot occupy more than 8,060 bytes.  That's the danger of using a catch-all tool like `to_sql` -- you don't know whether it's using best practices to create the table.  You may need take over the creation of your tables manually to make sure they're being done in an intelligent way.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you, there was a file in there rejected for having a row size of 22,000.  Would there be any hope in creating a table in an intelligent way and still getting that data in there? Also, it's a combination of how many characters a column can have, as well as the amount of characters actually in the fields of a table that makes up this number right?

Comment: If your fields are declared `CHAR(xxx)`, then they always occupy that many bytes.  If you declare fields as `VARCHAR(xxx)`, then they are variable length and don't count against the limit.  You should read about it; Google for "sql server 8060" and there are lots of links.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for that information, I've done some more digging and ,to my surprise, it seems that the data is actually making it into the db. Only when I try to add a primary key to the newly created table and inserted data is it throwing me that error, but the data ends up staying? I don't understand how this is happening, but I'm not really complaining.